# Python : Error in comparing strings

Tags: python, string, compare, nltk

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
w = 'flabbergasted'
ws  = wn.synsets(w)

for s in ws:
    for l in s.lemmas:
        if str(l) == "flabbergasted":
            break
        else:
            print(l.name)
```

I was trying to compare the output of the synonyms of a word with a normal string, but I get this output instead of all those values after the word flabbergasted being removed.

flabbergast

boggle

bowl_over

dumbfounded

dumfounded

flabbergasted

stupefied

thunderstruck

dumbstruck

dumbstricken

How should I correct this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: why does the string contain \n?

Comment: why are you using str() twice within the comparison?

Comment: the traceback is self explaining

Comment: Which loop do you think you're breaking?

Comment: The inner loop. I want that the list beyond flabbergasted should not be printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're intending to acces the `name` property of the `Lemma` object.  To print everything *except* "flabbergasted", you could try:

```
for s in ws:
    for l in s.lemmas:
        if l.name != "flabbergasted":
            print(l.name)
```

which gives the output:

```
flabbergast
boggle
bowl_over
dumbfounded
dumfounded
stupefied
thunderstruck
dumbstruck
dumbstricken
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, guess that was a silly question. Thanks a lot.